# How do I test CIVICRM_SIGN_KEYS?

Tags: crypto

I want to play with CIVICRM_SIGN_KEYS. I'm clear on how to set up a key, but how do I test it?

I guess I don't understand where Afform and Authx get invoked.

Cheers,

Answer (score 4):

Here is a tool to generate sign/cred keys, which CiviCRM 5.50 now nags about, when we upgrade:

https://civisettings.symbiotic.coop/

The examples are randomly generated, and can be copy-pasted in the civicrm.settings.php (somewhat copied of idea of the WordPress salt generator).

Comment: thanks for the tool